# In-Place editing using Asp.net ajax

Tags: asp.net-ajax, scriptaculous, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am looking for a way to perform in-place editing on my webforms app.  Here is a link for this behaviour using scriptaculous: http://wiki.github.com/madrobby/scriptaculous/ajax-inplaceeditor)

I am using the .Net Ajax toolkit.

Does anyone know how can I do this???

Thanks,

Nicolas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've used a turtorial on encosia.com to do just that. It's pretty easy, and he has more articles on how to evovle the functionality beyond just the basic features:

http://encosia.com/2007/08/23/seamless-inline-text-editing-with-aspnet-ajax/